# vue.js routing shows the same component after first navigation

Tags: vue.js

My main.js is as follows

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import vueResource from 'vue-resource'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

import Registration from './components/Registration.vue'
import Login from './components/Login.vue'



Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(vueResource)
Vue.use(VueRouter)


const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: __dirname,
    routes: [
        { path: '/', component: Registration },
        { path: '/login', component: Login },
        { path: '*', redirect: '/' }
    ]
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: router,
  template: '<router-view></router-view>'
})
```

app.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <router-link to="/">Registration</router-link>
      <router-link to="/login">Login</router-link>
      <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

It loads the app.vue with Registration link and Login link. Registration component is loaded by default. When I click on Login link, login component is showing. When I click registration again, the url changes but registration component is not showing.

Comment: depending on the contents of your app.vue you can load it as a component, and then new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})

Comment: eidt your question isntead of posting a comment with code

Comment: @Deepak : your solution worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the contents of your app.vue you can load it as a component, and then

```
 new Vue({ el: '#app', 
           router, 
           template: '<App/>', 
           components: { App } 
         })
```